# Is a bounded real function defined on a singleton Riemann Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I know to be Riemann integral a real function $f$ must bounded be defined on a closed bounded interval. A singleton is technically a closed bounded interval so is this permitted?

Comment: Well... why not?

Comment: Its integral is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. And note that a function from a singleton into $\Bbb R$ is automatically bounded.

On the other hand, the integral of such a function will alwyas be equal to $0$.

Comment: I guess we can also say $f$ is continuous trivially on closed bounded interval and therefore Riemann Integrable.

Comment: Indeed we can.${}$